# xmlbeans and reserve word tags

Tags: java, xsd, xmlbeans

I'm trying to compile an xmlbeans jar from an xsd.   The xsd was provided to me from a vendor so I cannot change it.   The name attribute "CON" is causing XML beans to throw an exception as follows:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeLoaderException....(The system cannot find the path specified).    If I change the tag attribute to say "CON1", the problem resolves so it is definately something about the string CON that it does not like.   Is there a work around for this.  I include a simplified version of the schema that I've been using for test purposes as a reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="CON">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="TEXT" type="TEXT" minOccurs="0"  
maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="VALUE" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:minLength value="2"/>
                        <xs:maxLength value="4"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:simpleType name="TEXT">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="0"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="1023"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>    
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: CON is a reserved device name on windows machines.

Comment: Please cut/paste the *full* error message - including the "path" that's failing.

Comment: Tried it on my windows machine. scomp tries to create a file `...\classes\schemaorg
_apache_xmlbeans\javaname\noNamespace\CONDocument\CON\VALUE.xsb` and that directory name is indeed forbidden on a windows machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in XMLBeans: [XMLBEANS-352](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XMLBEANS-352)

`scomp` tries to create a file ...\classes\schemaorg _apache_xmlbeans\javaname\noNamespace\CONDocument\CON\VALUE.xsb This fails. The directory name `CON` is forbidden since `CON` is a reserved device name on Windows machines.

Providing a `.xsdconfig` file that maps the element to another name does not work. I tried.

Compiling the schema in linux and copying the resulting jar reportedly is the only solution.